# Categorize categorical data R

Tags: r

I am trying to categorize a column of categorical data

```
 current        |desired 
| DN974         | a   | 
| DN469B        | a   |
| DN469W;DN469E | b   |
| DN80          | b   | 
| EZDH01        | c   |
| DN971         | c   |
```

What I tried:

```
a <- c("DN974", "DN469B", "DN469W;DN469E", "DN80", "EZDH01", "DN971")
df <- data.frame(a)
df <- mutate(df, a=if_else((a=="DN974" | a=="DN469B"), "a", 
                          (if_else(a=="DN469W;DN469E" | a=="DN80"), "b", "c")))
```

I am trying with the if_else function, but i fail to make it work. I get the error
`Error: unexpected ',' in: "df <- mutate(df, a=if_else((a=="DN974" | a=="DN469B"), "a",  (if_else(a=="DN469W;DN469E" | a=="DN80")`

Am I using the correct function, and is so, what am I doing wrong? Thx

Comment: Use `df$desired <- sub("\\d+$", "", df$a)`

Comment: My reprex is probably too simplified, sorry. My actual data has more complex names such as EZDH01, DN469B and so on. So I need to specify which goes in to which group. As I understand your solution, it only removes the number?

Comment: Please update your post with an example that mimics your actual data rather than a simplified example

Comment: Tried again with an example that mimics the actual data

Comment: Remove the close `)` after `a=="DN80"` and put it at the end of the nested `if_else`'s.

Comment: It is not clear whether the values that are changed are based on any pattern or is it custom case.  Then, `df %>% mutate(desired = case_when(a %in% c("DN974", "DN469B" ~ "a", a %in% c(...) ~ "b", ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `ifelse`'s are a bad idea because they tend to be unreadable and bugs become easier to occur. Use `case_when`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

a <- c("DN974", "DN469B", "DN469W;DN469E", "DN80", "EZDH01", "DN971")
df <- data.frame(a)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(a = case_when(
    a %in% c("DN974","DN469B") ~ "a",
    a %in% c("DN469W;DN469E", "DN80") ~ "b",
    TRUE ~ "c"
  ))

df
#>   a
#> 1 a
#> 2 a
#> 3 b
#> 4 b
#> 5 c
#> 6 c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I agree the nested if_else is quite annoying to work with. This seems to do the trick perfectly. Thank you and akrun.